# Chaning number in a variable name

Tags: python, list, loops, numbers, addition

I am still new, and the title isn't the most accurate. I apologize.
I'm not going to go into the entire problem but I am having trouble with this specific part.

So heres the snippet of code:

```
num = 0
SongAttributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)

while True:
    print(SongAttributes)
    num += 1
```

So 'myMusic.getSongAttributes()' is a list of 5000 songs. I want to be able to print the details of the first song, which would be 'myMusic.getSongAttributes(0)', then the second which would be 'myMusic.getSongAttributes(1)', and so fourth.

To do this, I set a variable 'num' equal to zero, and put it inside the (). When I put it in the loop, it should add 1 every time to loop occurs, thus changing the song details every loop. But instead it just repeats the same thing over again.

I am stuck here and my professor isn't responding, anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should put "SongAttributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)" in the loop too.

You assigned the value to SongAttributes only before the loop so the value never changes

Answer (score 1):

You've already set `SongAttributes` to `myMusic.getSongAttributes(0)` & continually print that in your loop.

You need to call `getSongAttributes` in your loop:

```
num = 0

while True:

    SongAttributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)

    print(SongAttributes)

    num += 1
```

Your loop will also loop infinitively if there's no way to exit it.

Answer (score 0):

You set SongAttributes before the loop so it never gets updated, you should move it inside the loop as follows, (i would personally use `for` loop as it would take care of the counter and exit condition for me)

```
num = 0
while True:
    SongAttributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)
    print(SongAttributes)
    num += 1

for i in range(len(myMusic)):
    Attributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)
    print(SongAttributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of the SongAttributes variable should be inside the while loop

```
num = 0 
while True: 
     SongAttributes = myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)
     print(SongAttributes) 
     num += 1
```

Also, you should add a line to terminate the loop as well, or use a for loop. Otherwise it'll infinitely keep going and whatever code you're trying to run will not process past that loop.
Here's what it would look like

```
for num in range (len(myMusic.getSongAttributes())):
    print(myMusic.getSongAttributes(num))
```

Here I'm not assigning `myMusic.getSongAttributes(num)` to a variable to increase the performance of the code, you don't need to do that for small programs but it's a good habit to optimise.

I'm using `len(myMusic.getSongAttributes()`because you said it's a list of 5000 songs. If the length of the list is gonna be constant you might as well just think of that term as 5000.

Hope this helps